# select2 json displaying all options as .text() instead of selected

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2-4

http://www.codeply.com/go/i8A9BlgzGL

Above is the codeply example. The setup is really pretty simple. It has a json data variable, an input box, and a select2 box. when the select2 value is changed it puts the .text() value of the select2 into the input based upon an event.

What is easy / quick to notice is that all of the possible options from the json load as the .text() value. I have been unable to find a workaround for this. this problem does not appear to exist if I am using a server ajax call to load the data.

```
$('#outitem').select2({
    placeholder: 'Find Item',
    width: '90px',
    allowClear: true,
    SingleSelection: true,
    data: data
});
$('#outitem').on('select2:select', function(){
    $('#output').val($('#outitem').text());

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `text()` from the entire `<select>` element, including all the options.

Change it to get the text of the selected option only

```
$('#outitem').on('select2:select', function(){
    $('#output').val($('#outitem option:selected').text());
});
```

Comment: works perfectly, thanks. I have been using the code I listed above for quite some time without any problems until recently.